Unable to Expose Port 5432 in Astro on Windows 11: "Address Already in Use" Error
I’m working with Astro (Astronomer CLI) on Windows 11, and I encountered an issue when trying to run astro dev start. The error message is as follows:
Error: error building, (re)creating or starting project containers: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.


What I've Tried:

I made sure Docker Desktop was running before executing the command.
I tried changing the port in the docker-compose.yml file (to another available port), but the issue persists.
I've also verified that no other processes are using port 5432with netstat and docker ps.

However, I still can't resolve the issue. Additionally, I can't sign up for the Astronomer Forum due to an invite-only policy, so I’m reaching out to StackOverflow for help.

how are you exposing the ports in the config?
